# WPF FileWatcher update Image.Source Thread Conflict

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I want to update an image in my wpf when a file changes. My problem is that I'm getting an error saying Image object belongs to other thread so I can't edit the Image.Source. I want the image to change when the filewatcher event triggers. How should I do this?

I have something like this:

C# Class1:

```
void fileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    uiClass.UpdateImage(new BufferedImage(Path))
}
```

.xaml WPF uiClass:

```
 Image x:Name="Image"
```

.cs WPF uiClass:

```
public void UpdateImage(BufferedImage img) 
{ 
    this.Image.Source = img; 
}
```

Comment: The fileSystemWatcher works as intended.

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FileWatcher` event (`fileWatcher_Changed`) is fired on a background thread, from which you try to update the `Source` property of the image (via a call to `UpdateImage`). This fails with an error because (in simplistic terms) the `Image` control can only be updated from the UI thread.

As @aloisdg states in comments, you could use the `BeginInvoke` method of the dispatcher to shift the work from the background thread to the UI thread:

```
public void UpdateImage(BufferedImage img) 
{ 
    Action updateImage = () => { this.Image.Source = img };
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateImage);
}
```

The other way would be to have a property (on your `Window` or ViewModel or whatever) that represents the image source, and bind to that property from your XAML. Then it won't matter whether you change that property from a background thread or the UI thread.

It might be worth posting the source code for your `BufferedImage` class. At the moment you are trying to assign an instance of `BufferedImage` to the `Image.Source` property: I suspect that won't work how you are expecting, even once the threading issue is resolved.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Thank you very much for the clear and serious answer! :D
You saved me a lot of time and your answer was easy to grasp! :D